# IDA * Pseudocode explanation

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, a-star

I am trying to implement IDA* algorithm for n-puzzle problem. i find some difficulty in understanding Pseudo code which explained in [IDA *](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA%2A)

what is cost(node, succ)? - is that f value?

what is the value that i should pass in cost(node, succ) in

```
t := search(succ, g + cost(node, succ), bound)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cost(node, succ)` is the transition cost from `node` to `succ`.

A* is searching for a shortest (lowest cost) path from a designated start node to any node satisfying a goal predicate.  The nodes are connected by directed edges (transitions) that each have a cost. The states (nodes) and costs (directed edge weights) will depend on the problem you are trying to solve. There's no general formula for `cost(node, succ)`.

IDA* is just the iterative-deepening version of A*. It conceptually performs the same kind of search, just using less memory at the cost of more processing.